# Can I use a prepared statement against arbitrary database connections in Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

[Java 7/Oracle] I have a multi-threaded application in which I plan to use a database connection pool. I would like to use prepared statements; however, it seems that prepared statements contain and would therefore seem to be inextricably bound to a single database connection object. The paradigm I want is **NOT** "open a connection, prepare a statement, do the same query thousands of times, then close the connection" as seems to be the sample code everywhere; the paradigm I want is "precompile this statement so it is run as efficiently as possible - get a random connection from the pool - execute the statement against that connection - release the connection back to the pool". Is this even possible in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a connection pool then connections are not actually closed when you call `close` on the conneciton object. Instead it is returned to the pool. This is usually achieved by wrapping the original connection in a proxy which intercepts your call to `close`.

Many connection pools and some drivers offer the possibiity to cache prepared statements to remedy the problem of continuously preparing the same statements. Of course, because the prepared statement is linked to the connection, you probably will preprare the same statement for every connection in the pool.

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially what I'm going to have to do. I will keep a HashMap cache of prepared statements in each connection object that will get initialized on first reference (I think I've got a decent scheme by which I can use integer identifiers for each statement for more rapid look-up than by name) and reused on subsequent calls against a particular connection object. The number is low enough that it won't be too big of a resource waste, but it still leaves me feeling a little queasy.

Comment: @jackLThornton Hm, why don't you leave it up to your pool provider to cache the statements? Have a look at [Tomcat JDBC](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html), for example. You don't have to use the Tomcat container to use their pool.